# .net core 3.1 web.config with routing

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core, web-config

I tried publish my project on hosting, but I have some issues.

I have SPA (react) in same folder as .netCore(rest api).

I want SPA routing, thats why I set rule in web.config, but it is not working. When I remove handlers ("aspNetCore") section from config, it is works, but restApi doesnt.

Can anyone help me with web.config?

I just want routing with react and have working restapi on same domain myDomain.com/api.....
Thank you.

My web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
</rules>
       </rewrite>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\Horseedo.Api.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
 <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 654874ba-ab44-4982-a101-ee05ba73cc4e-->
```

Comment: its a long time ago i looked at a web.config but i thought it was possilbe to have conditions for the rewrites, so a specific path gets ignored and passed on ect

Comment: as you can see, I rewrite all routes to index.html, for react(client) routing, but I want using rest-api on route for example: myDomain.com/api/data

Comment: and if you negate /api routes from your rule it should let them through to your api

Comment: I tried it, it is works, but only when remove handlers (aspNetCore). Everytime when I publish my project, it generates this handler in config. I think that project need it but it doesnt work with it.